# transfer google analytics data to mysqli database using php

Tags: php, api, mysqli, server, transfer

I want to collect some data from visitors but it slow downs my website i created a file named tracker.php contains the following code

```
<?php


// get address using ip
function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
    $output = NULL;
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if ($deep_detect) {
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
    }
    $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
    $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
    $continents = array(
        "AF" => "Africa",
        "AN" => "Antarctica",
        "AS" => "Asia",
        "EU" => "Europe",
        "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
        "NA" => "North America",
        "SA" => "South America"
    );
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
        $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
        if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
            switch ($purpose) {
                case "location":
                    $output = array(
                        "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                        "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                        "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                        "country_code"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                        "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                        "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode
                    );
                    break;
                case "address":
                    $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                    break;
                case "city":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    break;
                case "state":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "region":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "country":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                    break;
                case "countrycode":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

// Function to get the client IP address
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
  }
  
  $userIp = get_client_ip($ipaddress);
  $email = $_SESSION['useremail'];

    $v_country =  ip_info("$userIp", "Country"); // India
    $v_country_code =  ip_info("$userIp", "Country Code"); // IN
    $v_state = ip_info("$userIp", "State"); // Andhra Pradesh
    $v_city = ip_info("$userIp", "City"); // Proddatur
    $v_address = ip_info("$userIp", "Address"); // Proddatur, Andhra Pradesh, India


    $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    $endtime = microtime(true); // Bottom of page
    $loadTime = $endtime - $starttime;



  if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){ 
  
    $sql = "sql goes  here";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  }
  else{
    $sql = "sql goes  here";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
  }

?>
```

as you can see the following code is using an external api to collect location data using ip address but it will reduces loading time of website.

i want a optimise solution to collect data without increasing loading time of website so i decided to use google analytics for data collection but dont know how to extract google analytics data and store it into mysqli server can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should download your report from GA into a .csv file, then you should read that data using php and converting it into JSON.

Here is a tutorial: https://thisinterestsme.com/convert-csv-file-json-using-php/

Then you should be able to use that data and send it to your DB engine.